# How to leave a file open and continue from where we left last time? C++

Tags: c++, file

Is there is a way to read in from a file until the end of a line, then go to another function do something, then come back afterwards to read in from the same file BUT from where we stopped last time (not from the beginning of the file)?

If yes, please provide a snippets. Code makes more sense to me than words. Thanks

Comment: `std::ifstream` already keeps it's read pointer state unless you call `close()`, so what's your problem actually?

Comment: Just don't close the file.  One way you can do this is to create the file object (assuming `std::ifstream` since this is tagged as C++) in main and then pass it by reference to all of the functions that need to read from the file.

Comment: *"Code makes more sense to me than words."* - Then could you provide some explaining what you mean?

Comment: I think he is opening the file in a function and then the file is being closed when it goes out of scope.  Re-entering the function opens it from the beginning.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/  Search for `ate`

Answer (score 0):

When opening a file for writing using `std::fstream::open()`, you have the options to set the file `openmode` as the second argument after the *filename*...

```
std::fstream file;
file.open("myfile.txt", ios_base::openmode::ate);
```

`openmode::ate` is the flag used to open the file with the input cursor positioned at `eof`.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/openmode/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/

Comment: Due to the new legal terms here on the stack I chose not to provide complete `haz teh codez` answers.  If the OP cannot figure how to solve his problem using the information I provided here, then I am unsure how to help him further.  Anyways, other than the lack of `std::` on `ios_base`, why will this not compile?  I am very interested in hearing the reason....

Comment: Scratch that, I see it now.